# Windows 8 app read from page

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8

I need to read the text from a webpage using a windows 8 metro app ?
I tried some examples but none of them seems to works...
I think I used httpwebresponse class.
Can someone explain me how it works or give a tutorial that would work ?

I'm using C# .

Comment: This question looks like it was answered over here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482402/webclient-class-doesnt-exist-in-windows-8

Answer (score 0):

Look at HttpRequest, HttpReponse, HttpWebRequest.GetReponse() functions and classes in MSDN.