# Port this from WP7 to Windows 8

Tags: c#, xml, windows, linq, windows-8

I can't find how to replace Webclient from this code.

What's the new namespace and way to create it in Windows 8....new to Win 8 dev.

Any tips or posts would be helpful, or any code below.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
 Uri url2 = new Uri("http://www.buscms.com/api/XmlEntities/v1/stops.aspx", UriKind.Absolute);
 client.DownloadStringAsync(url2);


 void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Error == null) 
    { 
        if (e.Result != null) 
        { 
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result); 
            XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusExpress.ClassLibrary"; 
            var routeNames = (from n in doc.Descendants(ns + "ArrayOfStop") 
                             select new RootContainer2
                             { 
                                 Departures = (from s in n.Elements(ns + "Stop") 
                                          select new Departures
                                          {

                                              StopName = s.Element(ns + "StopName").Value,    

                                          }).ToList()
                             }).Single();

            listBox2.ItemsSource = routeNames.Departures;





      } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTTPClient instead of WebClient, like this:

```
public async Task<string> DownloadTheString()
{
    HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync("http://www.buscms.com/api/XmlEntities/v1/stops.aspx");
    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // Return the downloaded string
    return result;
}
```

Here is another very similair question too: [WebClient class doesn't exist in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482402/webclient-class-doesnt-exist-in-windows-8)

Comment: Thanks....I am getting this error though...

The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: If you have this code in a function you have to change the function to something like this:
public async Task<bool> DownloadMyStuff(){
// CODE HERE
}

Comment: I updated the answer to write it as an async function that returns the downloaded string instead. For more info on working with async, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx