# Windows Store - Loading Images from URL - poor performance

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am populating a `GridView` with about 40 images that are online. I have got a DataTemplate for my Grid where the `Image.Source` binds to the URL (e.g. "http://foo.jpg") like so:

```
<Image Source="{Binding imgUrl}" >
```

The Problem is, this method is very slow as all the images have to be downloaded first over the internet (the actual size of the images can be 500x500 although within the app I only need a size of about 250x200). This causes the 40 images to pop up in the `GridView` which takes some time. How could you improve this?

Pre-download them to the local storage? Scale the images? ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you pretty much answered this yourself. If the source url is slow, you pretty much have no choice but to pre-download them. Except if you control the source, then yeah like you said, definitely scaling and/or converting to a more format that doesn't take much space like gif if the quality becomes ok.

Answer (score 0):

If pre-downloading them something you are okay with, maybe look into using [WebClient's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx) [DownloadDataAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144190.aspx). As the download complete event fires off, you can update your collection of images.

Comment: Unfortunately WebClient is not supported in Windows Store Apps.

Comment: Ah, okay. I wasn't aware of that. Seems like this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9485128/609879) might be a good solution for WebClient,